# Using hook_form_alter to Hide a field

Tags: 7, hooks, forms

```
function custom_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

global $user;
$node = node_load(arg(1));
$num  = $node->field_node_reference['und'][0]['nid'];
$val  = node_load($num);
$event_noderef_uid = $val->uid;



if($form_id == 'regester_node_form'){
 
if($user->uid == $event_noderef_uid){
 $form['field_NAME']['#access'] = FALSE;        
 }
```

How to hide `field_NAME` only if `($user->uid == $val->uid)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can clean up the code a bit by using [hook_form_FORM_ID_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7.x):

```
function mymodule_form_regester_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  global $user;
  $node = node_load(arg(1));
  $num  = $node->field_node_reference['und'][0]['nid'];
  $val  = node_load($num);
  $event_noderef_uid = $val->uid;

  if($user->uid == $event_noderef_uid){
    $form['field_NAME']['#access'] = FALSE;        
  }
}
```

Other than that, if `field_NAME` exists in the form and the condition is true, `access` will be set to FALSE. If you are testing this as user 1, you may not be seeing the results you desire as that is the superuser. It would help if you posted the form you are trying to alter and what its structure is for `field_NAME`. Probably a really good case to write an automated test for as well.

Comment: Can I use EntityFieldQuery instead of  
  $node = node_load(arg(1));
  $num  = $node->field_node_reference['und'][0]['nid'];
  $val  = node_load($num);
  $event_noderef_uid = $val->uid;

Comment: Why to load a node since it is available in the `$form` variable?

Comment: @mchar it's "nodereference" inside node..